# Visual Studio 2019 Linux Platform ARM build outputs x86-64 binaries

Tags: c++, linux, arm, visual-studio-2019

I am doing a build using VS2019 and when selecting Platform ARM64 and when inspecting the resulting output binaries I find that the type of the file is x86-64 instead of the expected ARM type. When I compile locally using gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi I get the expected ARM type. Am I configuring my build in VS2019 wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: trying to build ARM64 programs for a robot using Visual Studio 2022 through WSL2. Although you can pick a Configuration labelled ARM64, Visual Studio does not automatically use the correct tools. To fix this do the following.

Start a WSL2 command line ("Ubuntu" from Start Menu) and install the cross-compiler by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install g++-aarch64-linux-gnu
```

Then in Visual Studio open the project Properties dialog and select the Platform: ARM64 configuration.

Under C/C++:

```
C Compiler = aarch64-linux-gnu-g++
C++ Compiler = aarch64-linux-gnu-g++
```

Under Linker:

```
Linker = aarch64-linux-gnu-g++
```

You can check the resulting executable by shifting to the relevant Windows folder then asking about the file properties.

```
cd /mnt/c/your_path/bin/ARM64/Release
file your_prog.out
```